# App freezes when segue performed from button

Tags: ios, uibutton, segue

I have a button in my storyboard that presents a view controller with a modal segue. Every time this button is pressed, the app freezes (There is no crash and no error message). `prepareForSegue` is called and all the view controllers that should be there are there in code in `prepareForSegue`, but they don't appear onscreen. I can modal segue from the same button to another view controller just fine. Any ideas on why this is happening or how to fix it?

Things I have tried:

1. Deleting button or using a different button
2. Recreating the segue in IB

Comment: can you show some code about?

Comment: What code would you like to see? All this is just done in IB control-dragging segues.

Comment: @Kevin Can you post your prepare for segue method.

Comment: I just put a breakpoint there and po'd segue.destinationViewController to confirm that the viewcontroller was being created.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got Xcode to give me an error message... turns out I had done

```
if (self == [super init]) {
}
```

when I should have done

```
if (self = [super init]) {
}
```

which caused all sorts of memory problems.

Comment: for that I wanted to see your code :) some time is little mistake that break all the app

Comment: This is a bad practice, however, because it's all too easy (as you found out the hard way) to use `==` because you see that it's in an `if`. Much better is to break it out explicity, like `self = [super init]; if (self) { ... }`.

Comment: Wouldn't changing the "==" to "=" make the if statement always return true?

Comment: It will return true only when the super initialization is successful. This is basically how Obj-C handles failable initializers. The if statement is a guard against allocating memory for instance variables when the super call was nil.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in iOS 9 that was fixed by not setting any text in UITextViews, in the storyboard, that were in the destination view controller... bizarre but it fixed it!

[iOS 9 Segue Causes App To Freeze (no crash or error thrown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643765/ios-9-segue-causes-app-to-freeze-no-crash-or-error-thrown)