# iOS 9 and tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath to prepare for storyboard-segue?

Tags: uitableview, segue, uistoryboardsegue, ios9, didselectrowatindexpath

Currently updated my app from iOS 8 -> iOS 9 via xcode 7. For some reason everytime I try to prepareForSegue via a UItableView the selected row in the tableView does not prefrom a segue as supposed to. This was currently not the case in iOS 8. Xcode gives no errors or warnings aswell. The app just freezes when selecting a tableView-cell item.

Any clue what may causing this strange behaviour? Some simple example code:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"FromSearchToShowTaskSegue"]) {
            ShowTaskViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
            Solution *s = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
            vc.taskId = s.id;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Did you solve it? If so, can you please suggest how?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the fix on this other Stackoverflow question:
[prepareForSegue Freezes after updating to iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650040/prepareforsegue-freezes-after-updating-to-ios9)