# Xcode 7 crash: [NSLocalizableString length] 30000

Tags: ios, crash, xcode7, nslocalizedstring

The app just hangs on iOS7,8,9, makes 30000 calls to [NSLocalizableString length]
The cpu is on max.

see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16001 also

```
(lldb) bt 
* thread #1: tid = 0x2cb4df, 0x0349065c Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 6, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbf728ffc) 
  * frame #0: 0x0349065c Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 6 
    frame #1: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #2: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #3: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #4: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #5: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #6: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #7: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #8: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #9: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #10: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #11: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #12: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #13: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #14: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #15: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #16: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42 
    frame #17: 0x03490680 Foundation`-[NSLocalizableString length] + 42
```

Answer (score 22):

I checked the English checkmark in addition to the Base, and it stopped having problems.

[image: settings]

Comment: The problem with this solution though is that if you add a new textview to the storyboard for example, you have to remove the localisation, and re add it. Otherwise you might get the same problem as before.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helped recreating localizable strings file in storyboard.

Comment: I found that if I checked English, ran the app, then unchecked English, things were fine. Definitely seems like a bug in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

If one does not need Base internationalization, one can turn it off in the project settings - this fixed the problem in my case:

[image: turn off base internationalization]

When turning base internationalization off, the affected files (storyboard, launchscreen) are moved from `base.lproj` to `en.lproj`. It looks like there are problems when base.lproj is used without at least one (primary) language.

I encountered the problem after creating a new project in Xcode 6.4 and then opening it in Xcode 7.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is change the Localization native development region From China to United States.

[image: img]