# After updating Xcode to IOS 9, app stucks on splashscreen and initial viewcontroller is not loaded

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios9

Using a `storyboard` in Xcode, I have an application that worked nicely, but after latest Xcode update (IOS 9), the app stucks on the splash screen.
`DidfinishLaunchingWithOptions` is succesfully called and reaches the end of the function, but the initial viewcontroller is not being loaded.

If I switch the initial view controller to another screen, it works fine..

How can it be that the initial view controller is not loaded for the one screen, and it does get loaded if I set it on the second screen?

I first thought it had perhaps to do with constraints, or UI elements, but even after resetting constraints and removing the UI elements (which are just a set of buttons) still the same problem. There is only basic code in the viewcontroller.m .. (and it is not being called because I have console logs in every function)

Anybody with the same problem or a solution?

**Edit 1:** It seems that it is caused by one of the UI elements, after removing them all, the view does load.. now trying to add them one by one to see what causes the error.

**Edit 2:** I tracked the error to one imageview plus textview in the view, without the imageview and textview the view loads, with the image and textview it does not. Selecting a different  image for the imageview does not seem to matter. Trying to find out why this imageview or textview is giving errors.

**Edit 3:** *(not applicable anymore)* The view in question has 4 images and 4 textviews in a grid, it seems that the images press away the textviews, and when this happens, the view does not load. (perhaps some constraints cannot be resolved..)

**Edit 4:**
The view looks like this (I cannot post screenshot due to NDA)

```
Image              |           Image
Textview           |          Textview
--------------------------------------
Image              |           Image
Textview           |          Textview
```

If we use for all Textviews the same text, it works, if however we change the up-right Textview **shorter** text, it stucks and does not load..
Is this a bug?? I am really lost.. I repeated the same experiment 3 times, and each time I set the text to the short variant it does not work, for the a bit longer text value it does work..

---

**Edit 5, problem: text cannot be too small**

When we set the text of one of the four TextViews to a string that is smaller than ten characters, the view does not load. If we use strings that are bigger than ten characters (any string), the view loads.

This is a very very weird bug, we are now trying to change the bounding box sizes of the textviews, to see if it has something to do with that.

With a string of 9 characters, the view refuses to load. With 10 characters it loads fine, no problem at all. There are no constraint issues whatshowever.

When we use spaces to make it at least 10 characters, everything works fine...
This is definately a bug..

Comment: No, no one else. You're going to have give more information! You're not getting any messages at all in the console that might give a clue about what's happening here? It's completely silent?

Comment: It is completely silent, except for the Logs that I do myself in the DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions ..

Comment: "It seems that it is caused by one of the UI elements, after removing them all, the view does load." Ooooh, good detective work. I can see you're going to figure this out. When you do, be sure to answer your own question (you can even accept your own answer in 48 hours); this could be useful for others.

Comment: Can you check, whether this applies? http://stackoverflow.com/q/32688799/1396265 . My test app also seemed to be stuck - waiting a little longer resulted in a stack overflow.

Comment: It does not apply, It is a problem with one or more of the images.. but why? no clue yet.

Comment: Just a thought: When you keep the image views there, but remove the text views (which get pressed away), does the view controller load? Another option: Can you load the view controller from the storyboard (probably in the app delegate) and wrap that in a try/catch to see if an exception is thrown?

Comment: @Rainer, they are not pressed away, my assumption was wrong, see Edit 4. The loading with try catch is a good idea, I will try.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit 4: Did you try turning off base localization (if it is on at all)? I wonder if the text issue points into that direction.

Comment: no, we do not use localization, thx for the tip though.

Comment: I also did not use localization - it just got messed up when moving from Xcode 6.4 to Xcode 7 :-) (In my case it was a tiny test project freshly created only to test some keyboard issues...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so in the end the problem was a "too small" text in a textview below an imageview. Why the text was too small, or what "too small" means, no clue. Except that in this particular case it was 10 characters.

**The Solution**

I changed the initial text of each textview to a string with at least 10 characters. And I change the text after loading the view programatically to the text I want. This works as expected and the view loads.

I will try to file it as a bug to apple, because this can never be the correct behaviour. Thank you all for giving advice in this matter.

Comment: I wonder if you can create and post on github or similar a small project that demonstrates the issue all by itself.

Comment: I will try, lets see if the same bug appears when I start a new project and use the same interface.

Comment: My app stucks on iPhone 6S only and loads on second run. There is no textview in my initial view only labels. and all labels have lengthy text. Any advice?

Comment: Might be a different problem, what also worked for us was to setup a new project. Apparently something went corrupt in the older project.