# xcode 7 update causing hang at splash screen

Tags: ios, xcode

I just updated to xcode 7.0 and now my app is hanging at the splash screen.

I'm using a Google Maps Pod.

At first a clean & build caused a build fail stating that the Enable bitcode needed to be switched off.

I did that. My app now builds, however when I install it to the simulator or iPad it hangs on the splash screen.

There are no issue flags being displayed and the app appears to just hang forever until forced closed.

Everything was working fine until this xcode 7.0 update. Any ideas?

Comment: Certain interfaces just don't load, as we see from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721848/after-updating-xcode-to-ios-9-app-stucks-on-splashscreen-and-initial-viewcontro You might try what he tried, namely removing your interface and then putting it back again a little at a time until you find the source of the trouble

Comment: @matt Thanks for the link. I'll try that. Seems odd that these little things still plague this SDK.

Answer (score 0):

A previous post [xcode 7 issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721848/after-updating-xcode-to-ios-9-app-stucks-on-splashscreen-and-initial-viewcontro)

stated that there are some problems with content in the view controller when compiled with 7.0. The solution was to completely reassemble the views piece by piece until it starts working. This is not a practical response because of time constraints and financial aspects at work. I uninstalled xcode 7.0 and then went to the Apple developer archives and reinstalled xcode 6.4.

The app now runs correctly. Hopefully this will get sorted out by 7.1.