# Xcode 7.0.1 iOS 9.0 simulator won't go past launch screen

Tags: ios9, xcode7

Thanks for help!
For some reason my simulator or iPhone 6 won't go past launch screen.
I have a single view application. In the main storyboard  I have 1 view controller some labels and text fields. the launch screen story board I gave the view controller a colored back ground. no code yet. when I run all I see is colored background.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: I was so glad to find the answer, just hoped to help someone else find answer also.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a text area with string less than 10 characters
Thanks to @Bas van Stein for providing the answer in the question at

[After updating Xcode to IOS 9, app stucks on splashscreen and initial viewcontroller is not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721848/after-updating-xcode-to-ios-9-app-stucks-on-splashscreen-and-initial-viewcontro)