# Failed to generate disassembly for stack frame because the URL cannot be translated

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, ios9, xcode7

I have an app which can open a CSV file sent from an email and it display its content within the app in a different format (note that I cannot post the code used to do this).

However, every once in a while (about 2 times out of 3!), when importing a CSV from the email, the app freeze, the code is displayed as if I had a breakpoint in appDelegate, and when I press run in the debugger, the screen in Xcode becomes grey and displays the following message:

```
Failed to generate disassembly for stack frame because the URL cannot be translated: x-xcode-disassembly://stack_frame?
```

Does anyone knows what this message is and what could be the reason for it?

Note: I am using Xcode 7, and run the app in a mini iPad with iOS 9. (not simulator)

Thank you.

Comment: I am having same message using simulator and I am using XCode7, iOS 8.x, 9.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688799/xcode-7-crash-nslocalizablestring-length-30000) It solved my issue.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that I can't simply check only english, as my app can in fact change languages.

Comment: my app also include Swedish and it is working fine as well.

Comment: I did some testing. apparently, that checkbox determines the orientation of the storyboard, but my app has the Arabic & Hebrew languages, which are written right to left and they mess up my whole UI