# Failed to Generate disassembly for stack frame because the URL can't be translated in Xcode 7

Tags: objective-c, macos, ios9, xcode7

When i run my application in debugging by adding some breakpoints got the below Message can any one tell what these means [image]

Comment: After different queries on google I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32688815/2135229) and it solved my issue.

Comment: so i have a similar problem, however my project has many story boards. I have tried adding localization and then checking english to main storyboard but problem persists. I wonder if i need to add localization and then add english to all of them? I suppose i could try turning off base localization, but some day in the future it would be nice to have