# performSegueWithIdentifier won't push view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, swift2, xcode7

I've just updated Xxode to work with Swift 2.0. As usual, a lot of new problems showed up.

In my app I have a view controller that checks whether the user is logged in and present either login screen or the app's home screen. It's a pretty simple VC:

```
class WelcomeViewController : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if PFUser.currentUser() == nil {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue-require-login", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue-start-app", sender:self);
        }
    }

}
```

That used to work perfectly, but now it doesn't. The segue `segue-require-login` is of type "Present modally" and it works fine. The segue `segue-start-app` is "Show (e.g. Push)", but the view never gets pushed, even though the code is being executed (even `prepareForSegue` is called).

I've tried re-creating the segue, performing a Clean, cleaning the project's build folder but nothing seems to help.

Any thoughts?

Comment: In what way does it not work perfectly? Are there any errors?

Comment: Nothing happens, the screen is not pushed and no errors are presented, even though the code is executed.

Comment: maybe check your storyboard if the the segue identifier is still "segue-start-app". if thats not the problem then post your prepare for segue

Comment: The segue identifier is correct, I've checked. If it wasn't, XCode would throw a runtime error. Regarding the `prepareForSegue`, I only created it to check if it was being called, then removed it. My VC's code is exactly what you see above

Comment: @MarcosDuarte, does the view that will be pushed contain a UITextField?

Comment: @keno No, it contains a sub view controller that contains a `UITextView`. Anyway I don't understand why a text field could cause this problem, is it a bug?

Comment: @MarcosDuarte, I had a similar issue recently and used the approach in the following answer to resolve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643765/ios-9-segue-causes-app-to-freeze-no-crash-or-error-thrown/32661264#32661264

Comment: Thanks @keno, that solved my problem! Could make this an answer so I can close the thread? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in iOS 9 and Xcode 7 where if you have a UITextView with placeholder text, it prevents the segue from being triggered.

More explanation in the following answer:
[iOS 9 Segue Causes App To Freeze (no crash or error thrown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643765/ios-9-segue-causes-app-to-freeze-no-crash-or-error-thrown/32661264#32661264)

To fix it, try removing the placeholder text for the UITextView

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the same problem: I have a UITabelView with cells created from a nib file, when a user tap a cell this method is called:

[image]

and when I have the following method prepareForSegue:: the application crashes:
[image]

if I delete the line 129 Everything is ok , the method prepareForSegue:: open the right view and the label contactName is shown with its default text.
If I modify the method as follows prepareForSegue:: get exactly what you expect, without having any type of error:

[image]

let me know if you also get the same result