# ios app freezes when touching button or cell in tableView

Tags: iphone, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I made an app that worked perfectly using xcode 6 and ios 8.4. Went through the process of switching everything over to ios 9, xcode 7 and now when I run my app on my device, there are two actions that are causing my app to freeze.

1. Touching a navbar button to segue to another view. There are no fancy actions here, its simply just a + button with the sole function of segueing me to another view, and touching it makes the app freeze.
2. My home page is a table view populated with objects using Parse.com, and tapping any of the cells freezes the app as well, instead of taking me to a detail view of the object that I've selected.

When running the app, there are no crash reports coming up in xcode to point me in a direction.

Does anyone know of any bugs that may have caused this in the ios9, swift2, xcode7 updates? or could this be an issue in my code?

I've even tried to simply print a string to the console when the + button is touched to start to debug this piece by piece but it wont even print that which seems to me that it is freezing before it has a chance to even do anything associated with the button.

some other buttons work perfectly, and some make the app freeze. any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Are you using the `prepareForSegue:` method? Maybe you can set a breakpoint there and see what could be going on.

Comment: I am for the tableView cell, but for the standard button I mentioned in #1 no. I just set breakpoints for both and worked through it and it walks through to code no problem. Still freezes for both actions. I've even deleted the navbar button item (+), re-added it, created a new segue for it and it still froze.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643765/ios-9-segue-causes-app-to-freeze-no-crash-or-error-thrown

Comment: yes ^ that strangely enough is the issue. i've deleted the text within my uitextview and it works. Thanks for the help guys.