# xcode & swift: Navigate to ta bbar controller after facebook login in

Tags: swift

First of all let me say that I am very new to swift and ios development. Like 1 week new!

What I am trying to achieve is to navigate the application to a tab-bar-controller after user logs in, something like what happens when you first login to Tinder. 
What I have done so far was to implement the facebook login and it works as expected. Then I added a tab bar controller to the storyboard:

1- Do I need to connect my viewcontroller with facebook login in it to the tab bar controller?

2- I know that I need to use "mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" to redirect to another view controller ([Swift project not segue-ing properly after Facebook login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491397/swift-project-not-segue-ing-properly-after-facebook-login))
But I don't know how to get the identifier of the ViewController I want to load and pass to this function.

Please help! Is this the right approach? Any other thing I need to know or implement?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `UITabBarController` in your storyboard, make it the initial view controller (you can set this in the storyboard editor).  You should be able to leave your Facebook login view controller as is.  The next step you should take is to set a Storyboard ID to the Facebook view controller; that way you'll be able to use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. Go to your storyboard and select the Facebook view controller. Navigate to the identity inspector and set the Storyboard ID to a string value (it can be anything, but try to choose something easily recognizable).

[image]

Once that is done, go to the class that will be the first tab that is displayed upon launch. From here, add the method `override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)`.  Inside it is where you will add you code to present the Facebook view controller.  Here is an example class:

```
class FirstTabViewController: UIViewController {

    var canLogin:Bool = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        // Check to see if you need to log in
        if self.canLogin {
            // Get a reference to the storyboard
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            // Instantiate the login view controller
            let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("login") as! LoginViewController
            // Present the view controller
            self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            // After presenting the view controller, set a value to prevent it from poping up every time we navigate to this view
            self.canLogin = false
        }

    }

    //...

}
```

I added an extra property `var canLogin:Bool = true` so that the Facebook view controller will not show up if we don't need it.  You'll need to add your own implementation of this yourself to check if you need a login from the user.

The last thing I want to point out is how to dismiss the Facebook view controller when you are done.  You can achieve this with `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` in the class that is responsible for the Facebook view controller.  Call that method when you are ready to close the view.